# Can't prettify Python Beautiful Soup output. What are my options?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull the price of a product from a Romanian e-commerce website. I set up Beautiful Soup in Python but I'm having trouble actually cleaning the output to get a nice price.

This is my code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.emag.ro/mouse-gaming-logitech-g502-hero-16k-dpi-negru-910-005470/pd/D077JCBBM'
res = requests.get(url)
html_page = res.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
text = soup.find_all(class_="product-new-price")

print(text)
```

This returns quite a messy output. What methods could I use to prettify this? (preferably to get something simple like just '262.99 lei') I have tried using `soup.prettify(text)` but that errors out, giving a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'ResultSet'`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `soup.find_all(...)` returns a list of `Tag` instances. Read the docs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using `prettify` wrongly. First `find_all` return list so you have to iterate over it to see , second `prettify` doesn't take any arguments

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify)
text = soup.find_all(class_="product-new-price")
print(text) # list
print(text[0].prettify()) # accesing one item from list to see prettify
```

Answer (score 0):

`soup.find_all()` gives you a `list` of `bs4.element.Tag`. It's each of these that can be prettified.

You can concatenate them separated by newlines with `str.join()`.

```
>>> print('\n'.join(i.prettify() for i in text))
<p class="product-new-price">
 262
 <sup>
  99
 </sup>
 <span>
  Lei
 </span>
</p>

<p class="product-new-price">
 262
 <sup>
  99
 </sup>
 <span>
  Lei
 </span>
</p>

<p class="product-new-price">
...
```